# Pygame screen initialisation odd artefacts

Tags: pygame, pygame-surface

I want to learn pygame and code small fun games with it. So I have started learning this library.

After running this code;

```
import pygame
from sys import exit
pygame.init()

display_surface = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 400))
pygame.display.set_caption("My Game")

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit()
    # draw all our elements
    # update everything
    pygame.display.update()
```

I see a black screen but there are some artefacts in the screen, like this;

[The screen I am talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JawhE.png)

In the Youtube tutorial I am following, the screen is solid black. I don't understand why my screen is different and has some green points in it. My computer works normally and if I restart the program or the computer nothing changes. The pattern is always the same. I can of course fill the display surface black with extra code, and then it works.

My question is, why do I have these points on the display surface in the first place? If someone is knowledgeable about the topic; what do these green lines mean?
I am just curious : )

MacOS Mojave 10.14.6

Comment: Try `display_surface.fill(0)`

Answer (score 0):

You must clear the screen with `display_surface.fill(0)`:

```py
run = True
while run :
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
  
    display_surface.fill(0)

    # draw all our elements
    # update everything
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
exit()
```

Comment: Thank you Rabbid76. Do you know why that happens, or what is the meaning of it. Are they just some numbers in memory?

Comment: @omer Who knows. Likely the memory is not initialized and you see some garbage.